# C# WPF Custom Control XML Error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I try to run my custom control in my application, I get a strange error.

```
<UserControl x:Class="IBShowdown.BlackHole"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IBShowdown"
     mc:Ignorable="d" Height="100" Width="100">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="imgBh1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Black Hole 1.png"/>
        <Image x:Name="imgBh2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Black Hole 2.png"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My error message: 'Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3c. Line 8, position 5' XML is invalid. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce your error with the XAML you've posted above.

Comment: Can you share the file that uses the custom control?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because UserControl isn't closed?

Try either changing `Width="100">` to `Width="100"/>` just before `<Grid>` or end the file with `</UserControl>`

Comment: Thank you, I just added the </UserControl> (which solved 1 error), but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Looks fine and valid XML to me, sorry.